# In zookeeper distributed file system what to store in Zookeeper?

Tags: distributed, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to implement a file system using zookeeper with a mongo backend to store the data.

I'm trying to wrap my head around what all should be stored in zookeeper.  ACL's ,file metadata, database locations?